# Как исправить недопустимое значение свойства в css?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, google-chrome

Я хотел сделать баннер для своего сайта в HTML&CSS.И когда я запускаю код все выглядит неправильно.Поискал а Chrome ошибок и там говорится "Недопустимое значение свойства".
Вот код:

```
<h1 class="banner">My Web-site</h1>
```

Css:

```
.banner {
            background-color: blue;
            padding: 150px auto;
            margin: 0;
            width: 100%;
            text-align: center;
        }
```

Comment: `padding` не может иметь значения `auto`

Comment: margin имеет auto а padding нет да?Извините просто я новичок;

Comment: Да, вот документация https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding . Даже с логической точки зрения, чему может быть равно `auto` для внутренних отступов?

Comment: Да понял, спасибо вам!

Answer (score 1):

У свойства padding нет значения auto.

Answer (score 0):

У свойства padding только числовые значения, поэтому значение auto некорректно.
Ниже приведены варианты написания кода.

padding: 0;
Убирает все внутренние отступы у элемента.

padding: 10px;
Используя один параметр. Задает внутренний отступ со всех сторон.

padding: 10px 20px;
Используя два параметра. Первый - внутренний отступ сверху и снизу, второй - внутренний отступ слева и справа.

padding: 15px 25px 25px;
Используя три параметра. Первый - внутренний отступ сверху, второй - внутренний отступ справа и слева, третий - внутренний отступ снизу.

padding: 10px 15px 10px 25px;
Используя четыре параметра. Первый - внутренний отступ сверху, второй - внутренний справа, третий - внутренний отступ снизу, четвертый - внутренний отступ слева.